# Matlab GPU acceleration for loading large point cloud dataset

Tags: performance, matlab, crash, gpu, nvidia

I'm trying to load a large dataset of a million points in 3d space in MATLAB, but whenever I try to plot it (scatter or plot3) , it takes forever. This is on a laptop with Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 950, up to 224-MB shared system memory. This also sometimes leads to Matlab 2008a crashing. Is there a way to let MATLAB use a Nvidia GPU for plotting this dataset. I have another laptop with Nvidia Go 6150. I'm on Windows Xp and Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

### OpenGL

You can set the renderer used for figures in MATLAB.

http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1200/1201.html

To take advantage of GPU, You can set it to OpenGL

> set(0,'DefaultFigureRenderer','opengl')

Which

> enables MATLAB to access graphics hardware if it is available on your machine. It provides object transparency, lighting, and accelerated performance.

### Other ways

Also, the following link shows some ideas about optimizing graphics performance:

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f7-60415.html

However,

> These techniques apply to cases when you are creating many graphs of similar data and can improve rendering speed by preventing MATLAB from performing unnecessary operation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use CUDA the minimum card spec required is a G80, your 6150 sadly is too old.

[List of compatible cards.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA)

Comment: I'm not sure if CUDA affects plotting. I believed it is used to process vector data much faster, ie, using GPU instructions for vector/matrix operations

Answer (score 0):

There is Jacket, the commercial product to give GPU power to Matlab:

http://www.accelereyes.com/products/jacket

You can download the trial version (30 days, as I remember).